# Key value showing up as NULL in Postgres jsonb_to_recordset()

Tags: json, postgresql

I am trying to extract key values using jsonb_to_recordset(). This is how the original jsonb array looks like:

```
    select  journal.id as journal_id, journal.data::jsonb#>'{context,data,files}' as filelist from journal where id = 'aqpubr0ivqaaolpr4lp0';
```

The result is:

```
    [{"id": 0, "name": "MNDA_Template.doc", "extension": ".doc", "transferId": "aqpl61ple38cdebbrmgg"}]
```

As you can see, the key transferId has a value. But when I extract it using jsonb_to_recordset(), it extracts every other key value except transferId:

```
    select  j.id as journal_id,d.name as file_name,d.extension as ext,d.transferId as TxferId from journal j cross join lateral jsonb_to_recordset(j.data#>'{context, data, files}') as d(id int, name text, extension text, transferId text) where j.id = 'aqpubr0ivqaaolpr4lp0';
```

I get this:

```
journal_id           | file_name         | ext  | txferId

aqpubr0ivqaaolpr4lp0 | MNDA_Template.doc | .doc | (NULL)
```

Although I am defining the transferId in the structure, it misses it (only).
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because your identifier written in upper-case, you should use double-quote to get values inside them:

```
select * from jsonb_to_recordset('[{"id": 0, "name": "MNDA_Template.doc", "extension": ".doc", "transferId": "aqpl61ple38cdebbrmgg"}]') 
as d(id int, name text, extension text, "transferId" text);
```

Comment: I am extracting from a column, not providing a literal JSON. When I run it with double-quotes as suggested, it complains that it can't find the column corresponding to the key referenced in double-quotes:


`select   j.id as journal_id,
   d.name as file_name,
   d.extension as ext,
   d.transferid
from     journal j
cross join lateral
         jsonb_to_recordset(j.data#>'{context, data, files}') as d(id int, name text, extension text, "transferId" text)
where    j.id = 'aqpubr0ivqaaolpr4lp0';`


I get the error:
`column d.transferid does not exist`

Comment: use d."transferId"  instead of d.transferid

Comment: you did forget to add your column into  -> {context, data, files,transferid}

Comment: `select j.id as journal_id, d.name as file_name, d.extension as ext, d."transferId" from journal j ,
jsonb_to_recordset('[{"id": 0, "name": "MNDA_Template.doc", "extension": ".doc", "transferId": "aqpl61ple38cdebbrmgg"}]') 
as d(id int, name text, extension text, "transferId" text) where j.id = 'aqpubr0ivqaaolpr4lp0'`

Comment: transferId is part of the array {context, data, files,transferid} , which has been extracted already. The issue is that jsonb_to_recordset() is extracting all other keys (id,name,extension) but missing transferId.
[Check it out at] (http://rextester.com/DJBR22835)

Comment: i have removed cross join lateral from the query. you can use functions as lateral join without `cross join laetral` identifier. but you should put a comma at the end of the `FROM your table **,**` [http://rextester.com/IOAY68857](http://rextester.com/IOAY68857)